# Why layout_gravity not work for TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, layout-gravity

As the title description, when set `layout_gravity` for `TextView` in `LinearLayout`, this property does not work well, and when I set it through `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.gravity`, it does not work as well. But for `ImageView` with same way, it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.openssl.LayoutTestActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="xml"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup
            .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 15);
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textView.setText("Code");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup
            .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 15);
        layoutParams1.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the TextView you are creating programmatically, you are giving the TextView a `15dp` bottom margin, If you want to make the `TextView` itself at the bottom, set the gravity of the layoutParams without giving the view unnecessary margins:

```
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

And talking about the `textView` in xml, if you want to align the text itself of the `textView` to be at the bottom, set the height to match_parent and set view gravity to bottom:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="xml"/>
```

---

for the `TextView`in the code, try to set the height to match_parent and give the view a gravity of `BOTTOM` inside the `layoutParams` :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup
        .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: It works for `TextView` in `xml`, but although I cancel the bottom margin, the `TextView` in the code does not work as expected. And I want to know why this phenomenon happens, could you do me a favor?

Comment: I can wrap the `TextView` with a `ViewGroup` to solve this problem as well. 
 But I'm very confused about that the `layout_gravity` property does not work for `TextView`.